# How to solve weird ping spikes on laptop during online games

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ping

I have a Samsung np900 ultrabook with windows 8. When I'm playing http://www.haxball.com/ my ping increases for 5 to 10 seconds almost every minute. However when I'm playing on desktop computer there is no ping spikes.

Laptop uses Wifi Ethernet and desktop uses wired Ethernet.

I tried several browsers, no difference.

What would be the reason of this spike and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try a cable (Ethernet) connection instead of Wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Laszlo suggested above, try using a wired connection, if the ping spikes go away, then you know it is an issue with the wifi.

If this is the case, then I would guess there is either interference with your wifi signal, or another program is taking up all the wifi bandwidth.

In the case of interference, I would suggest you login to your router, and try changing the channel it is broadcasting on.  See if this helps eliminate the interference from other devices.

I would suggest you use the task manager to see if there are other programs using the internet, and if so, what ones.

Open up the Task Manager

You can easily use the tool by following a few simple steps.

1. On your Windows 8 start screen type “Task” and open the Task Manager. It initially opens in compressed mode and it only shows the list of programs that are currently running on your system.
2. In order to get in-depth information about applications and processes click on the “more details” button that is placed at the bottom right of the screen. When you will click on the more details button you will see that all apps are listed in an alphabetical order on the left side of the task manger whereas the right side of Task Manager shows the amount of CPU, Memory, Disk and Network space each application is consuming.
3. By clicking on the Performance tab you can see a graphical representation of the above. Note that in the Performance tab you can also see separate graphs for Ethernet and Wi-Fi.  This allows you to monitor your internet performance too.

Comment: Expanding on this, try switching between channels 1, 6, and 11 for your best chance at a good signal - for more: http://www.metageek.com/training/resources/why-channels-1-6-11.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you have many wireless networks around? Maybe there is radio mess in your range.

I have neighbor who use powerful Wireless-N router and I had serious network performance problems when he was watching youtube.

I asked him to reduce router power (in router configuration). He did it and problem is solved.

If you have similar situation and you can't talk with neighbour(s) - better (more powerful) router may help.

Answer (score 0):

0.Try connecting your laptop through a cable and you will see if the problem is in the wi-fi.

1.Probably the wi-fi signal is not good and something drains the connection every minute or so. Is there something on your laptop that uses the internet also and a lot?

Yes its an answer. One of the things that I have found to drain the internet connection are Windows updates, which start whenever they want and install whenever they want, especially on Windows 10. Another thing are torrents, google drive, dropbox and softwares that check for their own updates on their own time. A different problem is something blocking the Wi-Fi signal, because it moves its not stable, and when it passes through something like a big wall or iron, it can cause decrease in efficiency. The router might be broken or the router antenna might be broken. Channel overload, etc.

The router might be set to end frequencies (Channel 12 or Channel 1), 2400MHz or 2500MHz, some devices switch the channel automatically causing no connection and delay, stopping of the game, spikes until they reconnect to another channel, because the router is connecting and the game stops or delays while there is no internet. Some devices change from 2.4GHz to 5GHz when possible, again reconnecting which causes delay while the internet is off and reconnecting.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Yes its an answer, one of the things that I have found to drain the internet connection are Windows updates, which start whenever they want and install whenever they want, especially on Windows 10. Another thing are torrents, google drive, dropbox and softwares that check for their own updates on their own time.

A different problem is something blocking the Wi-Fi signal, because it moves its not stable, and when it passes through something like a big wall or iron, it can cause decrease in efficiency.

The router might be broken or the router antenna might be broken. Channel overload, etc

Comment: The router might be set to end frequencies (Channel 12 or Channel 1), 2400MHz or 2500MHz, some devices switch the channel automatically causing no connection and delay, stopping of the game, spikes until they reconnect to another channel, because the router is connecting and the game stops or delays while there is no internet. Some devices change from 2.4GHz to 5GHz when possible, again reconnecting which causes delay while the internet is off and reconnecting.